# How to find the 2nd closest ancestor in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My DOM looks something like this:

```
<li>
   <li><a class="editEntity>Edit</a></li>
   <li><a class="deleteEntity>Delete</a></li>
</li>
```

When the used clicks on 'Edit', I want to change the outer `<li>` to `<li class="selected>`.

I tried something like this, but this is not working:

```
$('li a.editEntity').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').closest('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: loop in all childs and stop (and apply whatever you wish) in the second child. I would have a look at jquery's .each() I'll psot example below

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go up a parent:

```
$(this).closest('li').parent().closest('li').addClass('selected');
```

It wasn't working because [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) starts with the *current* element, and so if you call it on something that matches the selector, you get back the same thing you started with.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eriwu4/2)

Or you can use `parents` with the [`:eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$(this).parents("li:eq(1)").toggleClass("selected");
```

Note that `:eq` uses 0-based indexes, so `:eq(1)` is the *second* parent `li`.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eriwu4/3)

Your quoted HTML is invalid, though (an `li` [can't directly contain an `li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)); I assume you meant:

```
<li>
   <ul>
      <li><a class="editEntity>Edit</a></li>
      <li><a class="deleteEntity>Delete</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

...or similar.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$('li a.editEntity').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: That will add it to *all* of the parent `li`s, including the immediate parent of the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

following my previous comment.. here's the example promised... :)

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
  });
```

Stop at the second index

Further info can be found here

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to add active class depending on the page. This is working 100% for multi level sub-menus of AdminLTE 3, just put this code in the footer section of your page.

```
var url = window.location;
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item a');
const currentLink = [...allLinks].filter(e => {
    return e.href == url;
});

currentLink[0].classList.add("active");
currentLink[0].closest(".nav-treeview").style.display = "block ";
currentLink[0].closest("ul.nav-treeview").closest('li').classList.add('menu-open');

$('.menu-open').find('a').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).parents().hasClass('active')) {        
        $(this).parents().addClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add explanation. Code only answers are discouraged on SO, and considered low quality. Most upvotes accumulate over time as future visitors learn something valuable or insightful, that helps them solve their own coding issues. Consider editing to add an explanation as to how/why key parts of your code solves the OP's issue.